# Thread.sleep stops all nested Asyntasks

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am following tutes from codelearn, and trying create an AsyncTask which generates tweets and executes another AsyncTask to write to a cache file.
I have Thread.sleep, so the UI on first load waits until the Tweets are written to cache file. First I execute AysncTask `new AsyncWriteTweets(this.parent).execute(tweets);` then sleep for 10 secs.

But in logcat I can see that AsyncWriteTweets also gets executed after 10 sec sleep. Hence onPostExecute gets executed before the tweets are written to the cache file, giving a blank screen.

```
public class AsyncFetchTweets extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private TweetListActivity parent;
    ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
    ArrayList[] temp;

    public AsyncFetchTweets(TweetListActivity parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        int result = 0;
        Log.d("ASync", "Calling asycn");
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
            Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
            tweet.setTitle("Title Async Very New" + i);
            tweet.setBody("Body text for tweet no " + i);
            tweets.add(tweet);
        }
        new AsyncWriteTweets(this.parent).execute(tweets);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        Log.d("Async", "on Post execute");
        this.parent.renderTweets();
    }

}
```

> PS: My assumption is AsyncTask should create a new thread, hence
>   Thread.sleep in parent should not stop child. If it is otherwise
>   please advise how can I overcome this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
new AsyncWriteTweets(this.parent).execute(tweets);
```

is wrong, AsyncTask must be executed on UI thread and not Worker thread. You might use Handler and post runnable to execute it safely.

For reference look into Threading rules:

> execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

another part of above link of interest is `Order of execution`, :

> Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

so your first asynctask must end before next one might start, but you migt bring back previous parallel behaviour by using `executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.` Still `execute` must be done on UI thread.

Comment: The edited answer, is the solution, I was typing it and @marcinj edited before I could. :+1

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation on [execute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)%20%20says%20that%20a%20single%20thread%20is%20used%20for%20all%20async%20tasks.%20%20So,%20you%20sleeping%20on%20the%20thread%20will%20stop%20other%20async%20task%20from%20executing.) method, a single thread is used for all async tasks.  So, if you are sleeping in your async tasks, it will affect other async tasks.

Give [executeOnExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...)) a try.